# StrongSwan IPsec PING only working once after ipsec restart

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, strongswan, openswan

Diagram VPN site to site:

[image: Diagram VPN site to site]

And a [GIF showing what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3uqQ.gif).

I create an IP route like this:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.132.146.166 eth0 eth1
```

And I have this iptable rules

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j ACCEPT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try exempting the IPsec traffic from your `MASQUERADE` rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Yes!, you were right, when I disable most of Iptables rules it works! Thanks!